# Add an option when long-pressing a number

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

Hi
    I'd like to add an option when long-pressing a number in the call list. Actually I have:

- Dial
- Send SMS
- Add to contact
- Edit before calling
- Remove

Is it possible to add an option there? Such option should start my application through an Intent when pressed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to an existing ContactManager application?

Comment: Yes, for instance the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially no. The Contact Manager App is made by Google, and you can't integrate with it in that way (unlike, say, with the contact actions such as Call, Facebook, Twitter that come up when you touch a contact). The only way you'd be able to change the behaviour of the Contact Manager is by rolling your own build of Android, in the way that Cyanogen etc. do, however I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: No, in fact I'd like to write an application that receives an Intent with a number and then operates on that number.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're out of luck. Consider integrating with the [Contact Badge](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_contact-badge/)